# Вставить данные из кода в метод запуска Client.run()

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyrogram

Делаю gui для pyrogram, использую tkinter. добавил там пару вводов для получения api_id и api_hash и номера телефона. Так вот, проблема в том, что pyrogram сам по себе просит через input номер телефона, типа  `Enter phone number:`, а мне вот надо из кода сразу вставить туда номер, затем код туда вставить, который далее также попросит pyrogram

после этого кода идет просьба от pyrogram номера:

```
 app = Client("my_account", api_id=xxxxx, api_hash="xxxx")

 app.run()
```

после app.run() pyrogram просит через input в cmd ввести номер телефона, но мне надо ввести номер из под tkinter с его entry, не могу понять как это сделать...

Answer (score 0):

Так, у меня получилось реализовать это, пришлось читать документацию...) Читайте документацию всегда и вы найдете ответ также как и я...
В общем если вы захотите запустить pyrogram не из консоли, а полностью через код и свой метод вставки кода например из tkinter,
Ну вам надо получить api_id, api_hash ну и номер телефона
Пример:

```
api_id=xxxxxx
api_hash="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
phone_number = "+xyyyyyyyyy"
```

Далее по конструктору:

```
app = Client("accountBot", api_id, api_hash)
```

Далее самое главное, используем уже не метод start, а метод connect

```
app.connect()
```

Теперь осталось получить код и авторизовать бота,

```
sent_code = app.send_code(phone_number)

code = input("Code?: ")

signed_id = app.sign_in(phone_number, sent_code.phone_code_hash, code)
```

Ну и затем `app.disconnect()` отвязываемся